# react native element: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `Image`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So basically using the Card element in React Native Element , I get the following error

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `Image`.
Bad object: {
  "0": {
    "width": null,
    "height": 150
  },
  "1": {
    "width": "100"
  },
```

I tried styling the props for the card component but I still get the error.
This is my component

```
 <Card
        title={item.text}
        wrapperStyle={{ width: 300 }}
        containerStyle={{ width: 300 }}
        imageStyle={{ width: 200 }}
        image={{ uri: item.uri, width: 200 }}
      >

      </Card>
```

Comment: why do you add width inside image prop?

Comment: to see if that would solve the problem as the image for the component actually has a width component